# ドメイン名からアクセスするとWelcome to nginx on the Amazon Linux AMI!となってしまいます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, nginx, unicorn

この記事（http://qiita.com/naoki_mochizuki/items/5a1757d222806cbe0cd1）を参考にして、IPアドレスからアプリケーションにはアクセスできるようになりました。ただAWSのRoute53で取得したドメイン名から検索すると、この下の画面がずっと表示されてしまいます。

[image: ドメイン名からアクセスするとnginxの画面に]

色々と調べていると問題はunicornかnginxのファイルの記述の仕方にあると思うのですが、どうやって書き換えればいいのか知識がないためずっと進展がない状態です。

unicorn.conf.rbのファイルは

```
# set lets
  $worker  = 2
  $timeout = 30
  $app_dir = "/var/www/rails/Triplor" #自分のアプリケーション名
  $listen  = File.expand_path 'tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock', $app_dir
  $pid     = File.expand_path 'tmp/pids/unicorn.pid', $app_dir
  $std_log = File.expand_path 'log/unicorn.log', $app_dir
  # set config
  worker_processes  $worker
  working_directory $app_dir
  stderr_path $std_log
  stdout_path $std_log
  timeout $timeout
  listen  $listen
  pid $pid
  # loading booster
  preload_app true
  # before starting processes
  before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if old_pid != server.pid
      begin
        Process.kill "QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      end
    end
  end       
  # after finishing processes
  after_fork do |server, worker|
```

そして/etc/nginx/conf.d/Triplor.confの中身は、

```
# log directory
error_log  /var/www/rails/Triplor/log/nginx.error.log;
access_log /var/www/rails/Triplor/log/nginx.access.log;
# max body size
client_max_body_size 2G;
upstream app_server {
  # for UNIX domain socket setups
  server unix:/var/www/rails/Triplor/tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 52.69.43.128;
  # nginx so increasing this is generally safe...
  keepalive_timeout 5;
  # path for static files
  root /var/www/rails/Triplor;
  # page cache loading
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
  location @app {
    # HTTP headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_server;
  }
  # Rails error pages
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /var/www/rails/Triplor;
  }
}
```

誰かどのようにコードを直せばいいか教えてもらえたらありがたいです！

Comment: multipost https://teratail.com/questions/52240

Answer (score 5, accepted):

server_name でIP AddressとFQDN両方指定してください。

```
    server_name 52.69.43.128 www.triplor.co;
```